problem with django migration / django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "players"
i am facing a problem when trying to migrate my project to docker postgres db!
Error is:
File "D:\TeamsProject.venv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2_init_.py", line 121, in connect
dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\TeamsProject.venv\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extensions.py", line 167, in make_dsn
parse_dsn(dsn)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: invalid connection option "players"
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'unfold',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'teams',
    'players',
    'matches',
    'common',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DB_HOST', default='localhost'),
        'PORT': config('DB_PORT', default='5432'),


    },
}

More context:
I have an app named players with a model Player in it.
DB configuration in settings.py was checked 100 times.
Also tried manually to connect with DB through Docker commands, and it works fine.
I cannot understand where this problem is coming from...
Checked all the code for some typos, checked db settings, reinstalled decouple and psycopg2 and 100 more things.

Without seeing any settings, it is hard to help you...

DB configuration in settings.py was checked 100 times please show us your DATABASES in settings.py. Take care not to reveal sensitive info.

If using decouple, have you tried entering your database credentials in settings.py instead of .env to see if it works?

Voting to close because it lacks the technical details to answer the question.

I added settings and installed apps.

Did you pip install python-decouple and in your settings import the config object: from decouple import config

Can you also try entering the literals for your DATABASES in settings.py without using decouple config?

I tried hardcoding the settings, but it didn't make a difference. However, using Decouple, the connection works fine. I verified it with Docker commands. Start to think that may be problem is with the env.
